# MySql Query very slow

Tags: query, mysql

I have a problem with a query on my website. When I load the page it is incredibly slow and only after over 12 seconds the content starts showing. I have installed a debug plugin and found the query that takes so long. The output of the plugin is the following:

> Time: 12,315.2ms (12.315196037292s)

Query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS meruca_posts.ID 
FROM meruca_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND (
    meruca_posts.ID NOT IN (
        SELECT object_id
        FROM meruca_term_relationships
        WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (14)
    )
)
AND meruca_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (
    meruca_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    OR meruca_posts.post_status = 'private'
)
GROUP BY meruca_posts.ID ORDER BY meruca_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Function: `WP_Query->get_posts()` (`meruca_` is my table prefix)

I have only basic understanding of mysql and can't really see, what may cause this to take so long. If anybody has an idea what I could change it would be much appreciated.
There are about 5k posts on the site right now which isn't too many and it is running on a dedicated server that should have much more than sufficient resourced for any query theoretically.

Comment: Please care about the readability and formatting of your questions. There's a WYSIWYG editor helping you to do that.

Comment: Have you tried running the same query directly inside phpMyAdmin or Adminer? The problem might be that you're doing a query inside a query, but you can only test that. The other question you should ask yourself is where the query comes from and if you couldn't do it more straight forward.

Comment: First thank you for the formatting, I was in a hurry still should have taken the time for that! Also you were right, I removed the nested query and it was lightning fast in phpmyadmin. The query comes from the option from my theme to not display certain categories on a page. I'm not quite sure how I can work around it but I will look into it for some time and update here, if I fix the problem. Again thank you for your efforts!

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue, however couldn't post my solution as an answer here due to my low reputation I can only do so in 8 hours. Until then it was solved by using category__in (array) instead of category__not_in (array). I will post the detailed answer with the new debug output as soon as I can! Thank you kaiser for helping me out.

Comment: Nice to see that the problem is gone. The restriction with 8 hours is there for everyone. Even we moderators would have to wait that time :)

Answer (score 0):

You must use a temporary table and an alias:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * 
FROM meruca_posts 
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID 
            FROM (
                    SELECT object_id as ID
                    FROM meruca_term_relationships
                    WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (14)
                )
            AS temp_object)
AND post_type = 'post' 
AND post_status IN ('publish','private') 
GROUP BY ID ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```